# Laravel Eloquent Relationship For Multiple tables

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relationship

There is 3 tables in my database: `Users`, `Biodata`, `Roles`.

`Users` and `Roles` are in relation with Pivot table `role_user`.
`Users` have role `student & employer`.

I want all the users with role `student` also with `biodata`.
I tried many times but couldnot find the solution. Hope you guys help me

```
$users = User::with('roles')->with('biodata')->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$users = User::with('biodata')->whereHas('roles', function($query) {
    $query->where('name', 'student');
})->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use whereHas , which is used to where query in realtion.

```
$users = User::whereHas('roles', function ($query) {
    $query->where('name', '=', 'student');
})->with('biodata')->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for this: `$user = User::with('roles', 'biodata')->get();`